# Why IndexSet can be initialized with negative one?

Tags: swift

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/indexset) about `IndexSet` said:

> The range of valid integer values is `0..<INT_MAX-1`. Anything outside this range is an error.

But this code works fine:

```
let indexSet = IndexSet(integer: -1)
```

And if we try with `-2`, it will produce a crash as expected.

Why this happened? Is it a bug or i missed something?

Tested on Xcode 9.4.1, Swift 4.1.

Comment: For a range there seems to be no limit, this works `let indexSet = IndexSet(integersIn: -100..<0)`.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. If you do `var indexSet = IndexSet(integer: -1); indexSet.insert(0)` then `indexSet.count` is `2`, but `for x in indexSet { print(x) }` does not print anything.

Comment: May be it's just me... but that documentation reads like "anything below 0 is undefined behavior". It may crash, it may be fine... all are acceptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. It comes from the fact that the initializer of an `IndexSet` is not failable. [Here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/6fc4cef671947d1d2482951853f7f82854473d91/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/IndexSet.swift) is the initializer as defined in the standard library:

```
/// Initialize an `IndexSet` with a single integer.
public init(integer: Element) {
    _handle = _MutablePairHandle(NSIndexSet(index: integer), copying: false)
}
```

Using unsigned integers should have been the way to go in order to be consistent with the definition:

> The range of valid integer values is `0..<INT_MAX-1`. Anything outside
>   this range is an error.

You could have this extension to be safe:

```
extension IndexSet {
    public init(unsignedInt: UInt) {
        self = IndexSet(integer: Int(unsignedInt))
    }
}
```

So when you try to initialize an IndexSet with a negative integer, it will give you a proper error message:

```
IndexSet(unsignedInt: -1) //Negative integer '-1' overflows when stored into unsigned type 'UInt'
```

Comment: The initializer shouldn’t be failable.

Either negative indices are disallowed and inserting them should trap, or they should be allowed and handled.

Comment: The workaround with extension works fine, but it makes sense what @AirspeedVelocity said about the initialization step. So, i also considered it's a bug.

Comment: @pacification I've started the answer with stating that it's a bug. The initializer is not failable by design, it should have been using  UInts instead of Ints. BUT Ints are so common that it would be bad language design, since casting to UInts would be ubiquitous with IndexSet initialization.